# Number of properties in Caché ObjectScript class

Tags: intersystems-cache, objectscript

I try to create ObjectScript class in Caché using dictionary(create class at runtime and compile it). Everything is ok, but when I try to add more than 857 properties to the class, it doesn't work. Error doesn't occur, but my class is not saved by clsDef.%Save().

Are here some limits to class definition? Is problem in number of properties or in size of class? Generated class should has about 9000 lines. Do someone know what causes the problem?

Thanks for ideas

---

*(reason: It's sql mapping class for table with 1000 columns, so I need to have 1000 properties and sql storage definition for every property)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main limits you can find in [documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20141/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GORIENT_appx_limits#GORIENT_appx_limits_classmem). And you can see that, limit for properties is 1000 per class. Maybe you'll check other limits, and will find where you have a trouble.